# I am getting same IP for every system - How to get IP Address via PHP coding

Tags: php, ip

Hello i am using this function to get IP Address of different systems..but everytime it returns the same value: 117.239.82.182

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
   if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
   {
     $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
   }
   elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
   {
     $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
   }
   else
   {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   }
   return $ip;
}
```

Comment: Is this code called by a `Cronjob`?

Comment: 117.239.82.182 is an external IP address. Are all the client systems in the same building / block / company?

Comment: yes.. same organisation.. I am checking this code in my company.

Comment: @disha_learning, if its on same organization its likely everyone has a same IP address. If you want to track a LAN IP, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` would work.

Comment: My requirement is to distinguish between each systems in the same organisation.. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] also returns same for each system.

Comment: Are you using some kind of web accelerator like [Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy)?

Comment: As others have mentioned and as you have acknowledged, if your server is outside your internal network, your clients will all appear from the same IP address, as they all go through the same gateway. If you were to host the server internally, then your code would return the local LAN IP address instead, i.e. 192.168.0.2. Unfortunately there is little you can do to get around this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** (The answer changed radically after some clarifications in the comments)

You could edit the **User-Agent** setting of the user's browsers. To see how to change the setting in various browsers [follow this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/). Then you should modify your PHP script to read User-Agent of the browser.
In PHP,`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` returns the browser's **User-Agent** setting. Eg. you can define as **User-Agent** something like **Company/System/1.02 Bla bla bla**. Then when you receive that same string you can assume it is coming from a known host.

Attention that the **User-Agent** can be easily spoofed. So this method is not secure. The secure solution would be to implement a **VPN** solution.

Comment: Ok. How do the systems connect with your PHP script?

Comment: basically im building an application to hold all users data in it.. every user can login into this system, and i want to restrict that no user can login from any other system.. !!

Comment: The users log in from a regular browser (eg. firefox, chrome, etc)?

Comment: by system you mean a computer or an application system?

Comment: but how will this helps in identifying each system uniquely.. Sorry.. but i am nt getting ur point exactly..

Comment: To identify each system uniquely you should assign a unique User-Agent for each system.

Answer (score 1):

117.239.82.182 is an external IP address. If all the systems that connect to the PHP server are behind the same external IP address, all of them will be notet as the same IP address.

Your script doesn't take the local IP. Don't think it's even possible. The IP you are seeing, is the IP of the firewall of your company.

Comment: yes.. but is there any way to track something unique in between these systems.. and they will be always hosted by same server.

Comment: @disha_learning By using a combination of all available information in server (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) Also this can result to duplications. PHP cant get mac addresses or SUID's so you are never able to identify a computer with PHP

Comment: So you mean to say it is impossible to find uniqueness in systems via PHP if they are hosted by same server.

Comment: If it's possible, the clients can tell the server who they are. Use input parameters when connecting. Example: http://subdomain.company.com/service.php?client=clientIdent

Comment: @disha_learning As far as I know it is impossible/unreliable. You should implement another strategy. Please, see my answer.